# Typescript use interface with strict values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I've got a typescript/react project in which I am using @material components. There are definitions for those under @types/material__*component*.
In the definitions there are often interfaces like (this one is from @types/material__menu/constants.d.ts):

```
export interface CornerBit extends MDCNumbers {
    BOTTOM: 1;
    CENTER: 2;
    RIGHT: 4;
    FLIP_RTL: 8;
}
```

Now if I wanna use CornerBit in my code I'd do:

```
import { CornerBit } from "@material/menu/"
```

@material/menu/index.js exports CornerBit from constants.js in which it is declared as:

```
const CornerBit = {
  BOTTOM: 1,
  CENTER: 2,
  RIGHT: 4,
  FLIP_RTL: 8,
};
```

Now when I import CornerBit like written above into my file and try to do:

```
const MyCornerBit = CornerBit;
```

I get:

```
TS2693: 'Corner' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

So I guess I'm importing just the interface somehow, not the const itself. How do I use an interface like that (all properties have explicit values) though?

That just feels completely useless:

```
const MyCornerBit: CornerBit = {
    BOTTOM: 1,
    CENTER: 2,
    RIGHT: 4,
    FLIP_RTL: 8,
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You’re trying to assign `CornerBit` to `MyCornerBit` and as the error says that’s not ok since it’s a type. If you want to say `MyCornerBit` is of type `CornerBit` then use : instead of =. It’s a bit unclear what you’re trying to achieve

Comment: Im trying to make MyCornerBit be an object with the values specified above. So that I can use MyCornerBit.BOTTOM, MyCornerBit.CENTER etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should just declare your const `MyCornerBit` as a `CornerBit` like this

```
const MyCornerBit: CornerBit;
```

There is no need to instantiate that const with matching properties

Comment: When I do `const MyCornerBit: CornerBit;` I get `TS1155: 'const' declarations must be initialized`

Comment: declare with `let` instead `const`

Comment: Hmm and then I need to disable tslint, because it tells me to use const when MyCornerBit is not being reassigned. But is is actually working. So thank you. Still seems a little strange to me though.

Comment: Okay, sorry. It is NOT working actually. Getting no compile time errors or anything, but runtime is telling me "Cannot read BOTTOM from undefined"

Comment: Does this `interface CornerBit` have an injectable decorator?

Comment: No. Nothing more than in my opening post.

Comment: Try to make a class that implements `interface CornerBit` and then instantiate an object of that class. It should work